# How does the common framework of the Paris Club ignore the goals of the Chinese and what does China seek to achieve in poor countries?

Tags: china, finance, international-monetary-fund, world-bank, global-south

> Another potential explanation is that Westerners designed the rules of
> the talks—**called the common framework—without accounting for Chinese
> practices and goals**, said Alexandra Zeitz, an assistant professor at
> Concordia University. “When you look at what’s actually in the common
> framework, it’s really just the Paris Club rules,” she said.
>
> China expects bondholders to take greater losses than official
> creditors and for multilateral banks to forgo some of what they were
> owed—a reversal of the Paris Club norm, people familiar with the
> matter said. Beijing didn’t formally agree to a deal until this
> October.

https://www.wsj.com/finance/china-turns-the-tables-on-wall-street-ed126a47

How does the common framework of the Paris Club ignore the goals of the Chinese? I am trying to understand what the Chinese seek to achieve by offering debt extensions to borrowers, but not debt reductions and by resuming lending faster after default than Western countries. So in my understanding Western countries seek debt restructuring and debt reduction and then wait it out until that debt is repaid, the Chinese seek debt restructuring without debt reduction and wants to keep investing and financing as soon as possible.

Comment: The Chinese are diversifying. Better have various countries as debtors, in various currencies. Helps with de-dollarization, too. They are hedging, instead of maximizing returns.